# Movie or book about people kept in a type of prison where if their name came up in a lottery, they'd be subject to experiments and/or organ harvesting

Tags: story-identification, movie, young-adult, dystopia

Looking for the title of a science fiction movie or book. It involved young people kept in a type of prison and facing a lottery where if their name came up they would face experiments on their body and or organ harvesting. There is also a bit of a love story and a mass escape by the prisoners.

Comment: These are some pretty common science fiction plot, actually; there are multiple works that will fit this description.  You seem unsure whether this was a film or a book, so is this something you have actually seen/read?  Or is it something you have only heard about second hand?  In the latter case, it may be very difficult to pin down the answer unambiguously.

Comment: @Mike Friske - If anyone correctly identifies the movie or book you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Sounds exactly like the movie "The Island" starring Ewan McGregor and Scarlet Johannson.

Comment: A planet named Shayol?

Answer (score 34):

Sounds like the premise for ***[The Island](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0399201/)*** (2005).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_(2005_film)):

> *The Island* is a 2005 American science fiction action thriller film directed and co-produced by Michael Bay. It stars Ewan McGregor, Scarlett Johansson, Djimon Hounsou, Sean Bean, Michael Clarke Duncan and Steve Buscemi.

> **In 2019, Lincoln Six Echo and Jordan Two Delta live with others in an isolated compound. This dystopian community is governed by a strict set of rules. The residents are told that the outside world has become too contaminated to support life with the exception of a pathogen-free island. Each week, one resident gets to leave the compound and live on the island by way of a lottery.**
>
> Lincoln begins having dreams that he knows are not from his own experiences. Dr. Merrick, a scientist who runs the compound, is concerned and places probes in Lincoln's body to monitor his cerebral activity. While secretly visiting an off-limits power facility in the basement where technician James McCord works, Lincoln discovers a live moth in a ventilation shaft, leading him to deduce the outside world is not really contaminated. **Lincoln follows the moth to another section, where he discovers the "lottery" is actually a system to selectively remove inhabitants from the compound, where the "winner" is then used for organ harvesting, surrogate motherhood, and other important purposes for each one's wealthy sponsor, of whom they are clones.**

Comment: I think loosely based on the book "spares" by Michael Marshall Smith!

Comment: And Parts the Clonus Horror from the 70s. They thought they were going to America.

Comment: Regarding the OP's two points: clones Scarlett Johanssen and the Ewan McGreggor are in love, want to stay together ... and how she knows his little tiks is even a plot point. There's also a memorable scene where a resident wakes up while having organs removed, runs in terror, and is roughly tackled.

Answer (score 4):

LogicDictates answer is probably closer, but this also sounds similar to the novel and movie 'Never Let me Go'.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Never_Let_Me_Go_(novel)):

> The story begins with Kathy H., who describes herself as a carer,
> talking about looking after organ donors. She has been a carer for
> almost twelve years at the time of narration, and she often reminisces
> about her time spent at Hailsham, a boarding school in England, where
> the teachers are known as guardians. The children are watched closely
> and they are often told about the importance of producing art and of
> being healthy (smoking is considered a taboo, almost on the level of a
> crime, and working in the vegetable garden is compulsory). The
> students' art is then displayed in an exhibition, and the best art is
> chosen by a woman known to the students as Madame, who keeps their
> work in a gallery. Kathy develops a close friendship with two other
> students, Ruth and Tommy. Kathy develops a fondness for Tommy, looking
> after him when he is bullied and having private talks with him.
> However, Tommy and Ruth form a relationship instead.
>
> In an isolated incident, Miss Lucy, one of the guardians, tells the
> students that they are clones who were created to donate organs to
> others (similar to saviour siblings), and after their donations they
> will die young. She implies that if the students are to live decent
> lives, then they must know the truth: their lives are already
> predetermined. Miss Lucy is removed from the school as a result of her
> disclosure, but the students passively accept their fate.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like *[Deadman Wonderland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadman_Wonderland)*.

> Deadman Wonderland is Japan's only privately operated prison, built after the Great Tokyo Earthquake on ground zero. Deadman Wonderland was founded by Rinichirō Hagire and run by Tsunenaga Tamaki. It gathers prisoners from all over Japan and raises money for the revival of the destroyed metropolis. To the public and the tourists that visit daily, Deadman Wonderland is a massive theme park-like facility run by the prison population. Unbeknownst to the general population, most of the prison's attractions involve cruel games of survival where many inmates lose their lives or are maimed for the entertainment of an oblivious public. The prison guards are also granted autonomy over how to punish the prisoners, which often results in bloodshed.

....

> Deadmen who are defeated yet survive the game have a part of their anatomy surgically removed for scientific research which is broadcast as part of the Corpse Carnival Post-Game Show. In a cruel twist, the doctor spins a bird-shaped macabre slot machine to determine which part of the loser's body will be removed (with the show being broadcast live to the other prisoners) by the doctor with the parts ranging from the eye (the right one was removed from Senji), vocal cords (which were removed from Nagi), and the kidney, part of the stomach, and hair (which were removed from Minatsuki). Other parts listed on the slot machine are hand, tongue, lip, nose, leg, tooth, nail, heart, lungs, and brain.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you explain how Deadman Wonderland matches the description provided in the question?